# Alter code to sum values from multiple files

Tags: arrays, perl, sum, rows

Curious if I can get a little help here.  I'm a perl newbie, and can't figure out how to convert the following code into something a bit more useful for my analysis.

This code presently takes the 1st and 4th column from a user supplied list of data files and puts them together.

What I'd like my code to do, for each row of the "current output" generated by this code (see below), is make a sum of these 4th column values (filea, fileb, filec).  Not quite sure how to implement this...

Current Output:

```
filea   fileb  filec

entrya  | 0 |10.2 | 0
entryb  | 0 | 0.0 | 1     
entryc  | 8 | 57.0| 46
```

desired output

```
         sum
entrya | 10.2
entryb | 1
entryc | 111
```

current code looks like this:

```
main: {


my %data;

foreach my $file (@rsem_files) {

    open (my $fh, $file) or die "Error, cannot open file $file";
    my $header = <$fh>; # ignore it
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        my @x = split(/\t/);
        my $acc = $x[0];
        my $count = $x[4];
        $data{$acc}->{$file} = $count;
    }
    close $fh;
}

my @filenames = @rsem_files;
foreach my $file (@filenames) {
    $file = basename($file);
}


print join("\t", "", @filenames) . "\n";
foreach my $acc (keys %data) {

    print "$acc";

    foreach my $file (@rsem_files) {

        my $count = $data{$acc}->{$file};
        unless (defined $count) {
            $count = "NA";
        }

        print "\t$count";

    }

    print "\n";

}


exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You say 1st and 4th, but the 1st column is a string... so do you mean you want the sum of the values in cols 2 and 4 for each row?

Comment: Sorry, that was bad wording.  The first and 4th columns come from another data file.  I'd like to sum the values for filea fileb and filec into one column.

Comment: List::Util has a sum method, take a look that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the `@rsemfiles` loop:

```
# create $total variable outside loop
my $total = 0; 
foreach my $file (@rsem_files) {
    my $count = $data{$acc}->{$file};
    # change unless to if, no need for NA
    if (defined $count) {   
        $total += $count;
    }
}
# move print outside loop so it happens once instead of per-file
print '\t$total\n';
```

Comment: Awesome, that does it!  Better than using additional libraries.  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, this is similar to an approach I tried, but for reasons that escape me, it wasn't adding things properly.  I think it might have had something to do with where it was in the loop.

Comment: One question, though if you wouldn't mind indulging, what does the line my $count = $data{$acc}->{$file};  do exactly?  This is what I think I was having trouble thinking through, and finding a simple reference for online

Comment: `my $count` declares the variable 'count' in the scope of the foreach loop. `%data` is a hash, out of which we are pulling the value associated with the key `$acc` (`$data{$acc}`). This value is a reference to another hash whose keys are the files, so we pull out the value associated with this particular file via `->{$file}`. So `%data` is a 2d structure and we need the keys `$acc` and `$file` to pull out a value, which is finally assigned to `$count`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach $line(@rsemfiles) {
    if ($line=~ /^entry/) {   
    #match the line starting with the word entry
    my $entry=$1; my $filea=$2; my $fileb=$3; my $filec=$4;  
    # make variables out of the column values
```

Now that you have these variables, you can do math on them.